# Duplicate rows in data frame based on Date

Tags: r, function, dataframe, duplicates, apply

Looking for a simple solution for the below problem
This is how my data looks:

```
ClientID    PatientID   Measure Value   CollectionDatetime
41  123456  Temperature           87    02-04-2017
41  123456  WBC                 1000    02-04-2017
41  123456  Temperature           83    02-05-2017
41  23456   WBC                10000    02-04-2017
41  23456   RR                   100    02-04-2017
41  23456   C-Ceratine            90    02-05-2017
41  23456   Temperature           87    02-06-2017
41  23456   Temperature           89    02-06-2017
```

This is how I want the output to be:

```
ClientID     PatientID  Measure Value   CollectionDatetime  Label
41  123456  Temperature            87   02-04-2017            1
41  123456  WBC                  1000   02-04-2017            1
41  123456  Temperature            87   02-04-2017            2
41  123456  WBC                  1000   02-04-2017            2
41  123456  Temperature            83   02-05-2017            2
41  23456   WBC                 10000   02-04-2017            1
41  23456   RR                    100   02-04-2017            1
41  23456   WBC                 10000   02-04-2017            2
41  23456   RR                    100   02-04-2017            2
41  23456   C-Ceratine             90   02-05-2017            2
41  23456   WBC                 10000   02-04-2017            3
41  23456   RR                    100   02-04-2017            3
41  23456   C-Ceratine             90   02-05-2017            3
41  23456   Temperature            87   02-06-2017            3
41  23456   Temperature            89   02-06-2017            3
```

The data should get replicated based on Patient ID and CollectionDatetime.
For each Patient ID, If it is 1st day once, 2nd day should have data of both 1st and 2nd and so on

Comment: How did you get the Labels?

Comment: Appears unclear. The rules about duplicating values and constructing "Label"s needs expansion.

Comment: Seems like an expanding window; each date should contain rows for the the current date and all preceeding dates, grouped by ClientID. The example could certainly be more succint.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `data.table`-package:

```
# load the data.table package & convert 'dat' to a data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

# create the 'lbl' variable and the number of times each row needs to be repeated

dat[, lbl := rleid(CollectionDatetime), PatientID
    ][, reps := abs(lbl - max(lbl)), PatientID]

# create a 2nd data.table with the repeated rows
# make a sequence for each replication
# add that to 'lbl' to get correct 'lbl'

d2 <- dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), reps)][, lbl := lbl + 1:max(reps), .(PatientID,lbl)]

# bind the original data.table and the new together
# remove 'reps' column (no longer needed)
# and order to match the expected output

rbindlist(list(dat,d2))[, reps := NULL][order(-PatientID,lbl,CollectionDatetime)]
```

gives:

```
    ClientID PatientID     Measure Value CollectionDatetime lbl
 1:       41    123456 Temperature    87         2017-02-04   1
 2:       41    123456         WBC  1000         2017-02-04   1
 3:       41    123456 Temperature    87         2017-02-04   2
 4:       41    123456         WBC  1000         2017-02-04   2
 5:       41    123456 Temperature    83         2017-02-05   2
 6:       41     23456         WBC 10000         2017-02-04   1
 7:       41     23456          RR   100         2017-02-04   1
 8:       41     23456         WBC 10000         2017-02-04   2
 9:       41     23456          RR   100         2017-02-04   2
10:       41     23456  C-Ceratine    90         2017-02-05   2
11:       41     23456         WBC 10000         2017-02-04   3
12:       41     23456          RR   100         2017-02-04   3
13:       41     23456  C-Ceratine    90         2017-02-05   3
14:       41     23456 Temperature    87         2017-02-06   3
15:       41     23456 Temperature    89         2017-02-06   3
```

You can achieve the same in base R:

```
dat$lbl <- with(dat, ave(as.numeric(CollectionDatetime), PatientID, FUN = function(x) cumsum(c(1, diff(x) > 0))))
dat$reps <- with(dat, ave(lbl, PatientID, FUN = function(x) abs(x - max(x))))

dat2 <- dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), dat$reps),]
dat2$lbl <- dat2$lbl + with(dat2, ave(reps, cumsum(c(0,abs(diff(dat2$reps)))), FUN = function(x) 1:max(x)))

d <- rbind(dat,dat2)[,-7]
d[order(-d$PatientID,d$lbl,d$CollectionDatetime),]
```

---

Used data:

```
dat <- structure(list(ClientID = c(41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L), 
                      PatientID = c(123456L, 123456L, 123456L, 23456L, 23456L, 23456L, 23456L, 23456L), 
                      Measure = structure(c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("C-Ceratine", "RR", "Temperature", "WBC"), class = "factor"), 
                      Value = c(87L, 1000L, 83L, 10000L, 100L, 90L, 87L, 89L), 
                      CollectionDatetime = structure(c(17201, 17201, 17202, 17201, 17201, 17202, 17203, 17203), class = "Date")), 
                 .Names = c("ClientID", "PatientID", "Measure", "Value", "CollectionDatetime"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```